# How to iterate an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, angular

I got undefined when I mapped my array of objects, this my `component.ts` :

```
availableHistorics: Array<AvailableHistoric> = new Array<AvailableHistoric>();

ngOnInit() {
this.getAvailableHistorics();
}
getAvailableHistorics(){
 this.service.getAvailableHistorics().subscribe(data => {this.availableHistorics.push(data);
 console.log(this.availableHistorics.map(item => item.keyword))
});}
```

This is my class :

```
export class AvailableHistoric {
id : String
keyword : String
nameToDisplay : String}
```

This is the service :

```
export class ProductService {
 private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/products';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getAvailableHistorics() : Observable <AvailableHistoric>{
    return this.http.get<AvailableHistoric>(this.baseUrl + 
 "/getAvailableHistorics")}}
```

This is the array I have :

```
[
{
    "_id": null,
    "keyword": "keyword1",
    "nameToDisplay": "name1"
},
{
    "_id": null,
    "keyword": "keyword2",
    "nameToDisplay": "name2"
},
{
    "_id": null,
    "keyword": "keyword3",
    "nameToDisplay": "name3"
}]
```

I want to get a list like that : ["keyword1","keyword2", "keyword3"]
Is there a problem with my code ?

Comment: Please provide the code from the service and the template

Comment: You need to show an example of the array of objects you're trying to iterate. `console.log(data)` inside the callback and copy-paste the results here.

Comment: @danijel.m I edited my post take a look

Comment: @GuyIncognito   I edited my post  with an example

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @WahabShah no I just got `undefined` in the console

Comment: `this.availableHistorics.push(data)` is unlikely to do what you expect it to do. Shouldn't it be `this.availableHistorics = data;` instead?

Comment: @GuyIncognito I can't do it like that because availableHistorics is an array

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Why would that make any difference? If it's an array and `data` is an array, you'll just get an array inside an array if you use push.

Comment: @GuyIncognito this is gives me a compiling error ! should I change the type of `availableHistorics` ?

Comment: *What* gives you a compiling error and what does the error say?

Comment: @GuyIncognito  the line `this.availableHistorics = data` gives me the error `Type 'AvailableHistoric' is missing the following properties from type 'AvailableHistoric[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

Comment: That's because the type in `return this.http.get<AvailableHistoric>` is wrong. It should be `<AvailableHistoric[]>`. (Also `Observable <AvailableHistoric[]>` in the previous line.)

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thank you :) Answer my question if you want

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the whole array to your availableHistorics list, so what you get is a nested array. Guy Incognito is right. You have to assign `data` to `this.availableHistorics`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the data you received is an array. And you are pushing it to an array. So the first element of an array is that array. e.g.:

```js
    let arr = [];
    let data = [1, 2, 3];
    arr.push( data )
    
    console.log(arr )
```

One solution is to replace the array

```js
let arr = [];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
arr = data;

console.log(arr )
```

A better solution is to use destructoring.

```js
let arr = [];
let data = [1, 2, 3];
arr.push( ...data )

console.log(arr )
```

[Read more about destructoring on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

PS: In your code this would be:

```
this.availableHistorics.push(...data)
```